# How to group or block a line of codes

Tags: flutter, android-studio, productivity-power-tools

I'm working with Flutter and Android Studio. I am trying to block ***ahem*** Group some line of codes so that I can just hide it by clicking the plus icon on the left hand side.

How to group a line of codes as a single block in Android Studio and/or Flutter?

Comment: Can you explain little more?

Comment: I now know that I am looking for region block thanks to Nibha Jain mentioned below in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not getting you wrong , you are talking about The Code Folding shortcuts in Android Studio.
They allow us to fold Code Blocks & Region Blocks so we can have more fine grained control over what code we are looking at in any given moment.
Have you checked these from official page:

```
Collapse/expand current code block  Control+minus or Control+plus   Command+minus or Command+plus

Collapse/expand all code blocks Control+Shift+minus or Control+Shift+plus   Command+Shift+minus or Command+Shift+plus
```

For creating a region you can do this simply :

```
//start region  method
    //your work here
//endregion
```

to open this

```
control+shift+ (plus +)
```

to close the region:

```
control+shift+ (minus -)
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts

or
Check this : https://proandroiddev.com/code-folding-in-android-studio-5d046517dadc

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for region blocks specifically. Please add code above for region blocks and I'll mark it an answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the block as a new method, then call it whenever you want, and you can set any conditions during calling or you can use Visibility widget to work with visibility of your block

```
 .....
if(!hidden)
 myBlock();
.....
```